# Bringing in data of two separate values from txt file into array

Tags: c++, iostream

So I am reading in data from a text file and putting it into an array. My code works fine and outputs the data except that instead of outputting data like

```
Q 5
```

it outputs it like this

```
Q
5
```

This is part of a greater assigment where I put all the values into a queue and sort them based on the numerical value which in the example above would be 5. But I just want help trying to get the data to come out like

```
Q 5
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int alphabet = 52;
char letter[alphabet];
int count = 0;

ifstream dataIn;
dataIn.open("CharInput.txt");
if (!dataIn)
{
    cout << "Error opening data file\n";
}
else
{
    while (count < alphabet && dataIn >> letter[count])
        count++;

    dataIn.close();

    cout << "The letters and their position are: " << endl;
    for (int stuff = 0; stuff < count; stuff++)
    {
        cout << letter[stuff] << endl;
    }
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

The data file is names CharInput.txt and has:

```
26
Q 5
W 3
E 8
R 7
T 2
Y 9
U 0
I 9
O 6
P 1
A 2
S 2
D 4
F 3
G 6
H 9
J 8
K 0
L 3
Z 1
X 5
C 7
V 4
B 7
N 2
M 8
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's something rather easy but I cannot think of it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data are output in lines because you are printing them ending with `std::endl`, which by its name, ending current line.

Instead, use a white space between each element and its count:

```
for (int stuff = 0; stuff < count; stuff += 2)
{
    cout << letter[stuff] << " " << letter[stuff + 1] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks!! but now it is outputting 26 Q 5 W 3 E 8 ... M 8. Is there a way to get them to line up like Q 5 then underneath that have W 3 ?

Comment: @Danielll Put a `cout << endl;` every 2nd iteration.

Comment: @Danielll See the edit, your formatting of data in the question misled me :)

Comment: It works!! Thanks for all the help!! I knew it was something rather easy that I was missing. Thanks!!